# sequelize integration to hapi

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, hapi.js

There are way many great examples of using **sequelize.js** with **express**.
I wonder if there are some people using sequelize with **hapijs**,
and how to make the entire thing painless.
How to get them to work together?

Answer (score 5):

**DISCLAIMER** : I'm a newbie with these two Frameworks also.

You can create an example like theirs http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express just replacing Express.JS to Hapi.JS and with some adjustments.

You can find the code result here https://github.com/jean-rakotozafy/sequelize-hapi-example.

I've taken some code snippets from this repository also https://github.com/agendor/sample-hapi-rest-api.

Hope that helps!